# Is there a "magnet" modifier I can use?

Tags: modifiers

The below is a simple cylinder with a torus around it.

I want the cylinder vertices to be "magneted" by the torus when I move it up and down my cylinder.  Is there a way to do it?  I can probably do this with displacement maps but I refer using a shape.

[image]
[image]

Comment: A cast modifier should do that.  Give the cylinder the Modifier and place the 'cast object' (an Empty?) centrally inside the cylinder and level with the Torus.  Parent the cast object to the torus. (child = cast object)
When the torus moves up and down, the swollen part of the cylinder will follow it,

Comment: THANK YOU.  This helped alot.  I've also played with the vertex groups on this modifier to create unique types of "bumps".

Comment: Glad tp hear all went well - must try your idea with vertex groups!  :)

Comment: Yea all you gotta do is weight paint them!.  But you probably already knew that.

Comment: No I didn't actually - I'm only a Blender hack myself.

Comment: There's also the Lattice modifier